# Script tags in TinyMCE fields are not saving correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I am running tinyMCE on my site and I'm trying to insert script tags. I am trying to insert my script tags into the body of the source of the tinyMCE instance.

However, when I do I get problems. When I submit the form including the tinyMCE element It strips the tags.

I have tried the following lines below with still no success.

- `allow_script_urls: true`
- `valid_elements : '*[*]'`
- `extended_valid_elements: 'script[language|type]'`

One thing I have noticed though that if I have to post the script code to the  section of the source code of the tinymce instance and it works. However, I need to be able to add it to the `<body>` of the tinymce instance so I can see previews etc of it.

Below is the script tag I'm trying to upload.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://resources.32red.com/ad.aspx?pid=237638&bid=3344"></script>
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Try the following:

`extended_valid_elements: 'script[language|type|src]'`

I see that you've already tried updating the `extended_valid_elements` property using

`'script[language|type]'` but you forgot to allow the src attribute for the script tags

so right now the `src` attribute is being stripped out.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and unfortunately, even when I added `script[language|type|src]` it still kept stripping out the `src`. On TinyMCE 3.5.11. Haven't found a fix yet, except for upgrading to v4, which is a bit of effort.

Comment: I kept removing TinyMCE plugins until I found the culprit - the `jwplayer` plugin I was using was stripping out the `<script src="...">` for some reason.

Comment: `extended_valid_elements : "script[src|async|defer|type|charset]"`

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a bug where if a script tag is wrapped in a div TinyMce dumps the script.
(even if you have extended_valid_elements correctly)
TinyMCE can be very annoying to use

Comment: I have just verified this today. Unfortunate. But glad to see someone else acknowledged it.

Comment: Grr. That's annoying. I think I'm hitting this too. I wonder if this was fixed in a particular version.

Answer (score 2):

What I did to solve the problem was putting the script block inside a tag `<code>` tag.

```html
<code>
     <script>alert("abc");</script>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this method
hiding from tinymce all inside script tag

```
protect: [/<script>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/g]
```

check https://regex101.com/r/cH35d9/1 for regexp:

`\s` - all space

`\S` - all not space

`*?` - repeat to first of `</script>`

and this is muililine because group of []* ignoring newline borders

Supports tinymce5, tinymce6 - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#protect