# How to store the script code (example: Google analytics) to database and show in the textarea? Similar to wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Using the tinyMCE as WYSWYG editor for text area. I can able to enter the script of Google Analytics and store into database, when I fetch it from database and show in textarea it doesn't visible.

Here is my textarea editor used.
    
    tinyMCE.init({

```
        mode : "textareas",
                extended_valid_elements:'script[language|type|src]',

        theme : "advanced",
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question and add all relevant code files? You're mentioning a query, but we se only a piece of `javascript`. Please add the relevant `php` code as well to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I cannot post a comment because of my low reputations but according to the following answer the problem can be wrapping the script tag in a div so it will not work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25723782/7995987

> There seems to be a bug where if a script tag is wrapped in a div TinyMce dumps the script. (even if you have extended_valid_elements correctly) TinyMCE can be very annoying to use